# looping and if statement within Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, nested, logic

I have a problem in that I want to go (via increments of 0.01) from 0 to 1 (that bit is easy) if an external condition (which is being evulated automatically) is false and stop the counter if the condition is true.

The condition is if a collision has occured between two objects. I know this part works correctly since I have tested it manually and within a loop. But stopping the counter if a collision has occured is proving tricky. I'm sure it is something very very simple that I'm missing out.

```
   def autoHandClose():
   global collisionDeteched # this is set to false but on collision correctly changes to true
   counter = 0 
   for x in range(100):
     if collisionDeteched == False:
        counter = counter + 0.01
        h.setGesture(hand.GESTURE_FIST, closeThumb=True, weight = counter)
     else:
      break
```

The weight parameter is from 0 to 1 (hence the reason why I want to go from 0 to 1 to close the hand) I can close the hand but can't get it to stop if a collision is detected. This method is assigned to a keyboard button press.

I'm guessing the logic is wrong, right?

Answer (score 1):

Is the check for 'collisionDetected' running on a parallel thread to this loop?  If not you will never exit the loop since the value of collisionDetected will never be updated.  Is this the case?

Also on a side note:

You might want to change your for loop to look a little more something like this to make your code cleaner:

```
for counter in range(0,1,0.01):
   ...
```

This will reduce the need to set counter in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the check for 'collisionDetected' hasn't thrown up any problems when using a slider to change the value of of counter. I'll double check. I don't know if I have my logic nested incorrectly too.

Comment: Does the value for collisonDetected ever get updated during the for loop though?

Comment: Yes it does. Its only when I add the if statements to interupt the for loop does it not work.

Comment: Try removing the interrupt statements and instead output collisionDetected at each step in the loop.  Then you can see if it ever changes before the loop terminates or after.